# Partial specialization using Concepts

Tags: c++, partial-specialization, c++-concepts, c++20

I was just reading the examples of C++20 Concepts. Now I am trying to create a function that will print out if the given type is a hash-table or not using concepts mixed with the partial-specialization. But unfortunately it doesn't work.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

template<typename T>
concept Hashtable = requires(T a) {
    { std::hash<T>{}(a) } -> std::size_t;
};

struct Foo {};

template <typename T>
void Bar() {
    std::cout << "Type T is not a hashtable" << std::endl;
}

template <Hashtable T>
void Bar<T> {
    std::cout << "Type T is a hashtable" << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    Bar<Foo>();
    Bar<std::string>();
}
```

I am using compiler version GCC HEAD 9.0.1, compiler flags are `g++ prog.cc -Wall -Wextra -I/opt/wandbox/boost-1.69.0/gcc-head/include -std=gnu++2a "-fconcepts"`. It gives me following compiler error:

```
prog.cc:18:6: error: template-id 'Bar<T>' used as a declarator
   18 | void Bar<T> {
      |      ^~~~~~
prog.cc:18:6: error: variable or field 'Bar' declared void
prog.cc:19:54: error: expected '}' before ';' token
   19 |     std::cout << "Type T is a hashtable" << std::endl;
      |                                                      ^
prog.cc:18:13: note: to match this '{'
   18 | void Bar<T> {
      |             ^
prog.cc:20:1: error: expected declaration before '}' token
   20 | }
      | ^
```

**[Live Demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/Ml9I5gpWqmPBEQTl)**

But my expectations were :

```
Type T is not a hashtable
Type T is a hashtable
```

**My Question**

Is it possible to specialize using Concepts?

Comment: I'm not sure one can define a function with `void Bar<T> {}`. That's not valid syntax.

Comment: @ForceBru Is there any alternative which uses concepts to do the same task

Comment: If by "same task" you mean "partally specialize a function template" then no. C++ never allowed it, concepts or not. Functions and function templates may only be overloaded.

Comment: @StoryTeller Can you tell me why c++ doesn't allow this code

Comment: Your specific code? Because it isn't syntactically correct. If you mean partial specialization of function templates in general, that's beyond the scope of this question. But there's probably an existing Q&A about it on SO.

Comment: @StoryTeller Thanks, I understood. My code worked fine using structs.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Function templates cannot be partially specialized (and never could be). Concepts don't change that rule.

However, function templates *can* be overloaded (and always could be). And concepts *do* make that easier:

```
template <typename T>
void Bar() {
    std::cout << "Type T is not a hashtable" << std::endl;
}

template <Hashtable T>
void Bar() {
    std::cout << "Type T is a hashtable" << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    Bar<Foo>();           // calls the first Bar
    Bar<std::string>();   // calls the second Bar
}
```

We say the second `Bar` is *more constrained* than the first `Bar`.

Comment: The code that follows the statement, "And concepts *do* make that easier:" is not quite demonstrative of how *concepts* make it easier.

Comment: @P.W. Try writing those two function template overloads without concepts.

Comment: @moyang_mm [Yes, it does](https://godbolt.org/z/ez1vPe). If it doesn't, it's a compiler error.

Answer (score 5):

I've replaced the function template specialization with structs specialization and my code is working fine. Look at the following code.

```
// This file is a "Hello, world!" in C++ language by GCC for wandbox.
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

template<typename T>
concept Hashtable = requires(T a) {
    { std::hash<T>{}(a) } -> std::size_t;
};

struct Foo {};

template <typename T>
struct Boo {
    static constexpr char value[] = "Type T is not a hashtable";
};

template <Hashtable HashT>
struct Boo<HashT> {
    static constexpr char value[] = "Type T is a hashtable";
};

template <typename T>
void Bar() {
    std::cout << Boo<T>::value << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    Bar<int>();
    Bar<Foo>();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to specialize using concepts?

No, it is not possible to partially specialize concepts. As per the online reference on [Constraints and concepts](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constraints):

> Explicit instantiations, explicit specializations, **or partial specializations of concepts are not allowed** (the meaning of the original definition of a constraint cannot be changed).

And as far as function templates are concerned, they can only be overloaded, not partially specialized.

Comment: Not sure why this is being downvoted - but it's worth pointing out that the question is about specializing using concepts but you're answering about specializing concepts. That's a correct answer - but it's not really what's being asked?

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, which is about using concepts for the purposes of specialization, not whether concepts themselves can be specialized.